# Get json unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to get JSON file with JSONP:

```
function getJson() {
    var url = 'http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json?callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        checkJson(data);
    });
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);
}
getJson();
```

The problem is that I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

So I searched online and I found few solutions, but non of them worked.

I tried to use Ajax instead and I tried to replace `$.getJSON` with `$.parseJSON` but I got this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h
```

The JSON file:

`{ 
    "id" : "1406032249536",
    "title" : "test",
    "data" : []
}`

Comment: It's not JSON if it's JSONP. Use $.ajax.

Comment: Also, _http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json_ doesn't exist. At least, it's not available to outsiders.

Comment: @Andy its blocked outside my country

Comment: Please check your output into `http://jsonlint.com/` it validate your data is proper or not

Comment: Use $.get(url,function(data){})

Comment: @AmitAgrawal — It shouldn't be valid JSON, the request is for JSONP.

Comment: @dystroy ajax dont support cross domain

Comment: Use $.get(url,function(data){}) try this instead of $.getJSON()

Comment: @AmitAgrawal its vaild

Comment: @user3217843 it says XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json?callback=?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: @user3825694 $.ajax lets you issue JSONP calls. Please have a look at the documentation.

Comment: means your url that you have mentioned will not allow the cross domain request.

Comment: @user3217843 of curse its not.. this is why I cant use ajax or get

Comment: @dystroy I know that, why do you think I said I cant use ajax

Comment: @user3825694 — Unless the site you are requesting the data from is explicitly providing a means for you access it cross domain, you can't make the browser request it directly at all.

Comment: why u don't try Zepto.js file for cross domain.i have used it its working for me.

Comment: @user3217843 what do you mean? how can I do it?

Comment: @user3217843 — Using a cut-down jQuery clone won't solve the fundamental problem (which is that the same origin policy forbids cross domain access of data with JavaScript unless there is an explicit permission given).

Comment: @user3825694 — Ignore the zepto.js suggestion. It won't help.

Comment: down load the Zepto.js file and incorporate it into your application.

Comment: @Quentin I cant see any other solution, so I guess I have to try this one...

Comment: @Quentin Do you know any other idea? I saw other website use ashx file...

Comment: @user3217843 Zepto didnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a `callback=?` in your URL, you are making a JSONP request.

The response for a JSONP request must be a JavaScript application. It should consist of a function call (to the function defined by (in PHP terms) `$_GET['callback']`) with one argument (the data you are asking for).

You are getting JSON back, so the service you are trying to connect to does not support JSONP (at least not with the standard `callback` argument — consulting their documentation might give you a different argument to use).

---

You could make a standard XMLHttpRequest (by taking the `callback=?` out), but you said (in comments) that that gives you a complaint about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` not giving your site permission to access it.

---

If you control the JSON endpoint, you could change it so it supports either JSONP or CORS (which is what provides `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`). It sounds like you do not control that endpoint though, so that isn't an option.

---

This leaves you with one option: Use a proxy.

Make the Ajax request to your own server. Have a server side program running on your server make the request to the JSON endpoint and return the data.

You could also look at using a third party proxy, such as YQL, but that will probably suffer from the geographic restrictions you mentioned in another comment on the question.

Comment: Ok, I thought about making a text or just a json file that auto update from the url. Is it possible or its still will give me the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Comment: That sounds almost exactly what I suggest in the final section of this answer, the only difference is that you are doing it on a schedule instead of on demand. You won't get cross origin problems if you make the request to the third party server from your *server*. You won't get cross origin problems if you make the request from the browser to the same site as is hosting the HTML page.